# Cycles - how to do mist AND emission glare?

Tags: 3d-view, camera, compositing-nodes

I cant even get mist to work in compositing, and my attempts having glare as well as mist are failing- despite following tutorials exactly I just get a render that is all one color, instead of mist/glare. Setup is:

[image]

Sorry for low quality, snapshots currently broken here. What do I need to change - my mist pass depth is set correctly for my scene.

Comment: Just to verify that the mist pass is as it should be, does it look correct if you plug the mist pass straight into the viewer node?

Comment: it dos but there is no mist - just the image